# OpenGL Perspective Texture Flickering

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures

I have a very simple OpenGL (3.2) setup, no lighting, perspective projection and a simple shader program (applies projection transformation and uses texture2D to read the color from the texture).

The camera is looking down the negative z-axis and I draw a few walls and pillars on the x-y-plane with a texture (http://i43.tinypic.com/2ryszlz.png).

Now I'm moving the camera in the x-y-plane and this is what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqDbO.gif.

My question is now: How do I handle the flickering of the wall texture?

As the camera centers the walls, the view angle onto the texture compresses the texture for the screen, so one pixel on the screen is actually several pixels on the texture, but only one is chosen for display. From the information I have access to in the shaders, I don't see how to perform an operation which interpolates the required color.

As this looks like a problem nearly every 3D application should have, the solution is probably pretty simple (I hope?).

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?  Why are you using deprecated GLSL builtin variables in GL 3.2 code?  What was wrong with imgur?  Where are your texture coordinates?

Comment: I don't think its relevant as its a general problem. I'm pretty new to OpenGL and GLSL, this is pretty much just copied from some sample and seems to be functional. Just posted it to show that I don't perform any fancy operations in GLSL.

Comment: Anisotropic filtering can help *a lot* for cases like this, but in extreme cases you just have to adjust the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to understand the images, but from what you are describing you seem to be looking for MIPMAPPING. Please google it, it's a very easy and very generally used concept. You will be able to use it by adding one or two lines to your program. Good Luck. *I'd be more detailed but I am out of time for today.*

Comment: Mipmaps seem to reduce the effect, but not entirely negate it. Could this be because of the quality of the generated mipmaps (via glGenerateMipmaps)? Should this be done manually?

Comment: There are several techniques for mipmapping, but the most basic way (applied via glGenerateMipmaps) is also the best. You can try some texture filters like gl_Linear on min and mag, maybe that'll help. Other than that there's not alot I can think of, after all it's simply attempting to draw an ugly triangle. The best thing to do is just take a texture that looks really good. Are you sure you did the mipmaps right? Keep in mind that the textures you use right now are extra-prone to the effect, it will be less with "normal" textures.

Comment: Looking at your moving gif i think you might have another problem on the skewed wall, maybe you have some infinite texture coordinates or something, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm going to say it again here : Anisotropic filtering!